# set icon to left in CSS and HTML

Tags: html, css

I am building an App and I am new in `css` I am stuck on a Problem.

I am trying to move an icon on `left and up` BUT it is still on the `right corner` , I have also tried `text-align :center;` but it didn't work.

template.html

```
<style>

.icon-form-container button {
    background-color: #f5f8f9;
}

.icon-edit-container button,
.icon-form-container button {
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 10vw;
    width: 10vw;
    max-width: 90px;
    max-height: 90px;
    min-width: 74px;
    min-height: 74px;
    font-size: 2.7em;
    color: #acd8aa;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
}


</style>




    <div class="icon-form-container">
        <button id="receiver-input" onclick="send_link({{ user.id }})" ><i class="far fa-smile grid-wink"></i></button>
    </div>
```

When i run this then the icon is keep showing in the right corner.

I have no idea what is wrong in the css.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank You in Advance.

Comment: Weird, running your exact code on my machine (firefox browser) the button is already on the top left corner, is there more to your code?

Comment: No sir, When i add `right: 10px;    bottom: 600px;` init then it worked and now i think i can make it left.

Comment: So you are trying to move the icon within the button from the middle to the top left of the button? Sorry I'm not understanding what you want to achieve

Answer (score 2):

```css
.icon-edit-container button,
.icon-form-container button {
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px
}
```

This should put the image at the top left corner.

Comment: Thank you very much BUT when i add `right: 10px;bottom: 600px;` then it worked